# SP2010 Show lists and libraries from a top site in subsites

Tags: 2010, development

I would like to create a web part page or custom layout page in several subsites which is displaying lists and libraries of my top site (root site collection).

One of the solutions I found was the following:
http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=106
It works but is not stable, we you have multiple web parts on your page and try to update/edit the individual views the page throws an error.

I'm looking for a stable solution

Answer (score 2):

You might have tried this, but just wanted to ask it out loud if you have tried using web reference in your webpart..

I needed to create a webpart that shows list from one site that lived on one farm to another site that lived on another farm.  I have total 3 webparts on this page and they work well in development and qa servers (they are not in production yet).

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/29544/6734

If this does not work for you, please let me know, it will be a good learning.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Krishna, my goal is less complex. Document library, Announcements, and discussion board from my root site in my site collection should be displayed on the home page of my subsites (so all in one site Collection) A requirement is also to have the default OTB webpart behavior when added the three components to a page through the add web part option... So the outcome should look like in Laura's video

Answer (score 0):

with the object model you can do what you want, or are you stuck with the use of native webpart?

Comment: Stefano, I like to avoid using the object model for the moment... Using Laura's technique works for one web part on the page when you add several native ones the page generates errors sometimes = instable

Comment: This is more of a comment to the original question than an answer. Not sure why questioner has accepted it. With a bit more  reputation, you will be able to [post comments everywhere](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Content Query web part** which comes out of the box with SharePoint. Laura has used importing and exporting of web parts which basically moves the XSLT like a Data View web part. This is easily achieved through SharePoint designer as shown in the video.

While Content Query web parts do not require SharePoint designer, you can follow [these steps](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/about-sharepoint-content-query-web-part) through the browser to display data from subsites or any site collection.

You can also think about styling the web part with XSLT in SharePoint designer. Refer [this post](http://www.astaticstate.com/2011/05/customizing-content-query-web-parts.html) that could help you achieve some customization.

Comment: Deepu, I'm looking for a 2010 solution only. In the past you had an option in SPD to add a content source from your root site in a site collection to your subsites. This option no longer exists in SPD 2010

Comment: Seams to work fine for 2010 to... I only wonder how to get the filter bar etc. in my xslt? Copy the normal document library appearance when added as a web part to a page?

Comment: It works perfect in 2010 too. You can filter the web part by editing it or you can filter the contents based on query string url - http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/02/18/Subclassing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-Adding-Dynamic-Filtering.aspx. Also check out this - http://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/filter-a-content-query-web-part-by-page-field-values-or-query-string-values-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I prefer the approach with the objectmodel that allows me to make portable and customizable webpart

Answer (score 0):

If you have simple needs - just display a flat list of items with no interaction other than hyperlinks - then take a look at my "Cross-Site-List-Snapshot":

http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Cross-Site-List-Snapshot.aspx

If you have more advanced requirements, then a Data View Web Part, Web Services or the REST API are other lightweight options.